# Mutate with value match from 2 columns

Tags: r

I am trying to match if any one element of 2 columns(a1,b1) contains the value in other 2 columns(a,b) then mutate a new column with printing matching value else print `a` columnn in mutated column if no values present

```
df <- data.frame(a = c("one","one","six","nine"),
                 b = c("four","five","two","seven"),
                 a1 = c("ten","one","four","three"),
                 b1 = c("one","two","six","eight"))
> df
     a     b    a1    b1
1  one  four   ten   one
2  one  five   one   two
3  six   two  four   six
4 nine seven three eight
```

Expected Output:

```
     a     b    a1    b1 New_c1
1  one  four   ten   one    one
2  one  five   one   two    one
3  six   two  four   six    six
4 nine seven three eight   nine
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to reshape into 'long' format, and then do the comparison

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
 mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
 pivot_longer(cols = -rn) %>%
 group_by(rn) %>% 
 summarise(New_cl = replace_na(intersect(value[name %in% c('a', 'b')],
      value[name %in% c('a1', 'b1')] )[1], value[name == 'a']) ) %>% 
 select(-rn) %>%
 bind_cols(df, .)
#    a     b    a1    b1 New_cl
#1  one  four   ten   one    one
#2  one  five   one   two    one
#3  six   two  four   six    six
#4 nine seven three eight   nine
```

---

Or another option is to `paste` and extract based on the pattern

```
library(stringr)
df$New_cl <- str_extract(do.call(paste, df[1:2]), 
                   do.call(paste, c(df[3:4], sep="|")))
i1 <- is.na(df$New_cl)
df$New_cl[i1] <- as.character(df$a)[i1]
```